# get option values in array using map jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select, splice

```js
$('#btnadd').click(addBulletinBoard);

function addBulletinBoard() {
  var show = $('#show').val();
  var show1;
  console.log("before " + $('#show').val())
  if (jQuery.inArray("*", show) !== -1) {
    show1 = $("select#show option").map(function() {
      return $(this).val();
    }).get();
  }
  console.log("after :" + show)
  console.log("after " + show1.splice(0, 2))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="show" id="show" multiple="">
  <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Select...</option>
  <option value="*">All</option>
  <option value="1">option 1</option>
  <option value="2">option 2</option>
</select>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnadd">Submit</button>
```

I have a demo above. What I want to happened is when Selecting option from the select and the option `ALL` is among the selected. I want to get all option except the first one and the second. So I used map with splice. But as seen in the console it is not what I am expecting.

How to get option values except first two in jquery

Answer (score 1):

Can simply use `Array#filter()`

```js
$('#btnadd').click(addBulletinBoard);

function addBulletinBoard() {
  var show = $('#show').val().filter(function(val) {
    return val && val !== '*'
  });

  console.log("after :", show)

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="show" id="show" multiple="">
  <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Select...</option>
  <option value="*">All</option>
  <option value="1">option 1</option>
  <option value="2">option 2</option>
</select>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnadd">Submit</button>
```

Comment: I need to get all option values when I select/included among the selected the All. In your example when I only select All nothing is shown. Sorry must have missed that on the Question above

Comment: OK so if only ALL selected leave it in place?

Comment: No I mean if all is selected select all option except 0 and 1 index option.

Comment: Oh...so populate all the other values even if user didn't select them?

Comment: its like this. select only `all-> result is option 1 and option 2`, `select all and option 1 result is still option 1 and option 2`, `select all and option 2 result is still option 1 and option 2`

Comment: yes the main anchor is the option "All" selecting it will get all option.

Comment: And then remove `*` from results array?

Comment: Can chain the `filter()` to the `get()`

Comment: yes remove the blank and `*`. that is why I used splice(0,2) index 0 then 2 items. But what I get as result is index 0 and 1 which should be removed. Im clueless why

Comment: One simple way is use `gt()` selector `$("select#show option:gt(1)").map...`

Answer (score 0):

`splice` would return an array containing the deleted elements and change the original array. So `console.log("after " + show1.splice(0, 2))` would show the deleted elements that is not what you really want. Simply move `show1.splice(0, 2)` out of `console.log()` and it works as what you expected.

```js
$('#btnadd').click(addBulletinBoard);

function addBulletinBoard() {
  var show = $('#show').val();
  var show1;
  console.log("before " + $('#show').val())
  if (jQuery.inArray("*", show) !== -1) {
    show1 = $("select#show option").map(function() {
      return $(this).val();
    }).get();
    show1.splice(0, 2)
  }
  console.log("after :" + show)
  console.log("after :" + show1)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="show" id="show" multiple="">
  <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Select...</option>
  <option value="*">All</option>
  <option value="1">option 1</option>
  <option value="2">option 2</option>
</select>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnadd">Submit</button>
```